# Has anyone experienced any cURL error 28: timeout errors using php 7.4 and craft 3.5?

Tags: php

So the site was working on a new server. But over night I am now seeing the site hang and not load. When it does give an error it gives a cURL error 28 with connection timed out on various resources it may be trying to load like google or other apis.

Does anyone know if this is a craft issue or a server problem. As I said it was working until this morning!

Comment: Can you post the actual error from the log?

Comment: Seems to be working again now after requesting a support ticket from the server. I'll update if I get a response as to why it wasn't.